# How to install Windows 7 on a MacBook with HDDs and no optical drive, without rEFIt

Tags: windows-7, macos, ssd, boot-camp, refit

I just removed the SuperDrive on my MacBook Pro and replaced it with an SSD. So now my laptop has a SSD, and a HDD, but no optical drive. I have Lion on the SSD and I want to install Windows 7 on the HDD. Unfortunately, Boot Camp only will install Windows off of the Windows DVD. I have made a bootable Windows 7 thumb drive but my MacBook Pro won’t boot off it.

So my question is how can I install Windows on the other HDD?

I have thought about maybe using Oracle VirtualBox to install it on that hard drive, but I don’t know if that would allow me to boot directly into Windows. I really don't want to go down the whole virtualization route.

I know I could just take out the SSD, put back in the optical drive, run the Windows 7 DVD, take the optical drive back out, put the SSD back in. But that sounds like a nightmare.

Also, I really don’t want to use things like rEFIt.

Any advice?

Comment: Why won't it boot off the drive? Are you sure you created it correctly? (see [here](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/))

Comment: I have no idea. My windows computers will boot off the Win7 USB drive I made, but my Mac won't. I think it has to do with Macs using UEFI instead of BIOS maybe?

Comment: Did you enable boot from flash drive?

Comment: How do you do that? I just help down Alt and the flash drive wasn't there. How do you enable boot from flash drive?

Comment: You may need to use [this](http://refit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I kind of wanted to avoid using reFIT. Is it possible?

Comment: Don't know what to tell you then.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at Mac OS X's `bless(8)` command's man page, especially the `--setBoot` and `--legacy` options. I believe you can use that to get Mac OS X to recognize your bootable Windows 7 flash drive. That man page also mentions that you might need to use `fdisk(8)` to mark a legacy partition as bootable (active), so you might want to check that flag on your flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

Apple typically prevents models that ship with an internal drive from using USB media in BootCamp.  You can use the instructions found [on the atomicPC Forums](http://forums.atomicmpc.com.au/index.php?showtopic=51873) to enable the option on your machine.  It does involve editing one of the Bootcamp plist files.